# Can't fetch into varchar with t sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to fetch the ID and a serial number from a table in a cursor. As a test, I've written the following T-SQL

```
DECLARE @sensId AS int
DECLARE @serNo as varchar

DECLARE Sensor_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  id, serNo
    FROM    sensor
    WHERE   serNo in ('000000002C507650', '0000000038507650', '0000000034507650', '0000000070507650', '0000000044507850', '00000000843060B0');
OPEN Sensor_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM Sensor_Cursor
    INTO @sensId, @serNo;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
    SELECT @sensId, @serNo
    FETCH NEXT FROM Sensor_Cursor
        INTO @sensId, @serNo;
   END;
CLOSE Sensor_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Sensor_Cursor;
```

It returns:

```
59     0
60     0
61     0
62     0
```

Why the zeroes? What am I missing?

The query:

```
SELECT  id, serNo
FROM    sensor
WHERE   serNo in ('000000002C507650', '0000000038507650', '0000000034507650', '0000000070507650', '0000000044507850', '00000000843060B0');
```

returns

```
id  serNo
59  000000002C507650
60  0000000038507650
61  0000000034507650
62  0000000070507650
```

Comment: I presume you have an unstated reason for using cursor, not apparent in the example.

Comment: Yes, I posted a trimmed down query that simply displayed the area I was having a problem. The original is much more complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect

```
DECLARE @serNo as varchar
```

is defaulting to a length of 1, i.e. varchar(1). Instead, declare it as such:

```
DECLARE @serNo as varchar(20)
```

or whatever maximum length it needs to support.

Comment: Which is correct according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258242(v=sql.80).aspx. Per BOL: When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30.

Comment: +1, he who saves 2 seconds not specifying a varchar length, spends hours trying to debug the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Declare the varchar @serNo variable with an appropriate length, like

```
DECLARE @serNo as varchar(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the length of your varchar variable. The default is 1 character.

ALso cursors are generally a bad thing, it would be better if you can use some sort of set-based processing espciallly if you have lots of records. This might help you to see if there is a better way to do what you want:
http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Comment: I know, but this is a once in a while type query, so I'm doing it easy. Thanks.